# getGeneratedKeys feature is not supported by this database

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc, sqlanywhere

I am running SQL Anywhere 16.0 and trying my hand at the Spring JDBC templates. What I need to do is very simple: insert a row into a table, then get back the auto-generated ID value.

```
public int log() {
    SimpleJdbcInsert insertActor = 
            new SimpleJdbcInsert(ds)
            .withTableName("DBA.REQUESTS")
            .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("REQUEST_ID");

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("USER_ID", userId);
    parameters.put("DATA_TYPE_ID", getProductSku());
    parameters.put("PRICE", price);
    // ...more parameters

    Number requestIdNumber = insertActor.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
    return requestIdNumber.intValue();
}
```

But Spring repeatedly gives me the error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
  The getGeneratedKeys feature is not supported by this database
```

The driver I am using should support JDBC 4.0 (the library is dbjdbc16.dll and it is in the path, and sajdbc4.jar is in the Tomcat lib directory). The relevant database connection info from Tomcat is

```
    <Resource auth="Container" description="Pooled connection to the web database" 
    driverClassName="sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver" 
    maxActive="30" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/web" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:sqlanywhere:Server=web;UID=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;port=xxxx;LINKS=tcpip(PORT=xxxx)"/>
```

and the Spring application context for the datasource is

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/web"
            expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

So my question is, is there a way to configure things better so that this type of statement works?
**OR** if the database truly does not support this on some fundamental level, is there a non-ugly alternative for me to insert the values and get back the generated id.

**UPDATE:** It appears that the database driver does not support this feature. Suggestions here and elsewhere were to do the INSERT than a SELECT immediately following. The problem, of course, is if another user inserts into the table between those two statements you will get the wrong value and that would be quite bad in this case.

My workaround for right now is to use a class-level lock on the relevant DAO, and do the select based on several columns (not just IDENTITY) so that I can be 99.9% sure I'm getting the same row back. It is good enough to work. That said, I'd much prefer to have a transactional way of locking the table. I don't *think* marking the function @Transactional would work for this, right, as that just delays the commit until all statements are successful?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16932814/2144390) help?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that is exactly what I did.

Comment: Does you driver support returning the generated key? That is an optional feature in the JDBC 4.0 spec. You can determine whether it does or not by checking the JDBC database metadata using the `DatabaseMetaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys` method.

Comment: Ah -- optional feature -- that explains it. That method gives "no" as an answer, that is why Spring is showing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JDBC expert at all so I can't answer the question *directly*, but I can tell you that the SQL Anywhere server certainly does have this ability. If the JDBC stuff isn't working, you could use the [`@@identity`](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/identity-variables-wsqlref.html*d5e7044) variable. Fetching `select @@identity` which will return the auto-generated value for the last statement.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thanks Graeme! Unfortunately, this doesn't cover the case where another user has performed an insert before you run the select. If they have, you will get the wrong value and in this case it would be very bad. If there is a (JDBC) way to lock the table until the SELECT is done, that would be ideal.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Apologies, my description was incomplete - `select @@identity` returns the auto-generated value for the last insert statement _done on the current connection_. So if your connection inserts a row, then another connection inserts a row, `select @@identity` on your connection returns the id of the row _you_ inserted.

Comment: Very interesting. I use a connection pool though -- it is possible two users would share a connection, I think, unless there is some way to prevent that?