# return generated key preparedstatementsetter

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am trying to retrieve the generated key for an insert statement to an Oracle database. I'm using a PreparedStatementSetter with the jdbcTemplate. I've read the other [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932814/unsure-how-to-return-generated-column-id-value-using-spring-jdbctemplate-and-pre) on this topic here, but the answer basically proposes moving away from StatementSetters. Is there a way to retrieve the key while using a PreparedStatementSetter? The documentation on using PreparedStatementSetters to retrieve  keys is surprisingly sparse.

Here's my jdbcTemplate update statement:

```
    statementSetter.setUpdatedBy(...);
    statementSetter.setFileStatus(...);
    statementSetter.setCompany(...);
    int modifiedCount = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, statementSetter);
```

Here's my SQL string:

```
database.insertFileControlRecordQuery = INSERT INTO MY_TABLE \
  (PRIMARY_KEY_FIELD, FIELD2, FIELD3,...) VALUES (MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?,?, ...)
```

Comment: you need to fetch `MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL` first and then execute insert with known id

Comment: @Lashane, can you give more implementation details about what exactly you mean by "fetch" MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL? Where would that take place?

Comment: fetch == select, it should be executed before you prepare update statement

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. FYI, for Oracle SQL newbies (like me), you are SELECTing your MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL. Selecting from the table itself will return an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Using a NEXTVAL as suggested in comments is potentially hazardous: if some other process does an insert and commit in between you fetching the NEXTVAL and committing your insert, you'll have a different key than what you assumed.

Instead, I would suggest using the update-function which has provisions for returning a key, i.e. ...

```
JdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator, KeyHolder);
```

... from which you can determine the key.

An example to illustrate:

```
String insertQuery="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?)";

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
PreparedStatementCreator preparedStatementCreator = connection -> {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery, new String[]{"PRIMARY_KEY_FIELD"});
        preparedStatement.setString(1, field1);
        preparedStatement.setDate(2, field2);
        return preparedStatement;
};
jdbcTemplate.update(preparedStatementCreator, keyHolder);

Number primaryKey = keyHolder.getKey();
```

Note that the setting of the column which holds the primary key upon creating the PreparedStatement is essential for Oracle! Without it, you'll be getting the ROWID instead.